# What file is Bosch reading at the end of season 5?

Tags: plot-explanation, bosch

At the very end of Season 5 [*Bosch*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3502248/) sits in his house and engages what seems to be an old case file.

[image]
[image]

**What is this about and how is it related to the rest of the story?** The words on it, possibly names, say "Clayton, Daisy", but I can't quite make something of them. Also, the numbers don't seem to be dates rather than arbitrary LAPD file IDs or whatever.

Is this possibly related to him finding out about Chief Irving's evidence manipulation in the Borders case? Is he now starting to dig up other cases with Irving's involvement?

Comment: See Michael Connelly's novels *Two Kinds of Truth* (2017) and *Dark Sacred Night* (2018). From Maureen Corrigan's October 2018 [review](https://www.washingtonpost.com/entertainment/books/two-loner-detectives-find-each-other-in-michael-connellys-darkly-brilliant-new-novel/2018/10/30/11c411fe-dbd1-11e8-b732-3c72cbf131f2_story.html?noredirect=on&utm_term=.7e77efc44397) of the latter novel in *The Washington Post*: "Daisy was a 15-year-old runaway-turned-prostitute whose body was found in a trash bin in Hollywood nine years earlier."

Comment: @AnneDaunted But how would she be related to the rest of the story then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Daisy Clayson is the late daughter of Elizabeth Clayton who was in Bosch's group therapy session when he was trying to infiltrate the pill ring.

[image]

This is the same woman who overdosed in Bosch's contacts (Degner) kitchen. This is where he sees the Daisy RIP tattoo she carries.

[image]

She's also seen at the pill gangs desert location, extremely strung out.

[image]

Bosch learns her backstory in Ep 4 from Degner and that Daisy was murdered in 2009 and the case remains unsolved.

The references on the file seem to be a DR number (which is an LAPD Report Number) and CC which I would assume is "Cold Case").

Season 5 is based in a large part *Two Kinds of Truth* by Michael Connelly and since Season 6 has been confirmed it's likely that it will deal with the outcome of Bosch's investigation into Daisy's case.

This is the subject of *Dark Sacred Night* (by Connelly) which I haven't read yet but is covered on Wikipedia (deliberately not linked).

Comment: Oh, that makes sense! I totally didn't connect the dots there but it's quite obvious now, they talk about her daughter a few times even. Thank you.